# New sink plumbing advice

Tags: plumbing, sink

We have decided to get rid of our dual sink and go for a single large sink with a center drain.

Before we get started I wanted to just double check to see if it can be plumbed successfully without having to do a lot of cutting.  The black PVC pipe is not moveable, and I'd rather not cut that and adjust it.

I took the pipes off and did a rough fitment, just trying to get some advice if it looks correct and or acceptable.

This is how  it looks with the dual sink :

[image]

And I'm hoping I can plumb it so it fits like the next pictures.
[image]

[image]

At this point in time, as I mentioned, this is just a  rough dry fit to see what I'm dealing with, and only using the white pipes as reference.
(so things are not straight or lined up 100%)

Comment: Are you asking if it's OK to have the horizontal run from the center drain of the new sink before you get to the trap?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: The P-trap has a threaded fitting which you can loosen and swivel to adjust the angle too, if it helps shorten runs or reduce clutter.

Comment: FYI, the "black PVC" is almost certainly ABS, not PVC. If you need to work on it, you'd want the correct glue for ABS. You'll have some degree of adjustment from the threaded union on the trap allowing the loop of the **P** to be rotated. The input leg does need to be higher than the output leg (not true in your mock-up pictures.)

Comment: Great ,thanks for the help,,
Actually have another related question....Our new sink is deeper  than what we have now, only by 1 inch.. if i need to ,can i cut that  PVC vent  pipe at the back and move the Horizontal PVC pipe down a inch or so to accommodate the new sink?..( just thinking ahead )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current setup, you've got a horizontal run from one bowl to the other, then it drains into the trap. In your mock-up, you're using the exact same horizontal piece to show where the new single, center drain will go. You're wondering if it's OK to have a horizontal run before you get to the trap...

So long as it's not *truly* horizontal, but has the appropriate 1/4" drop per foot of run, you'll be just fine.